# How to get records for given contact id in this case?

Tags: trigger

I created a custom object named Related_Staff_Positions which is a child lookup to the contact object.

Whenever one saves a new record, in a trigger I wish to get all records in the Related_Staff_Positions object for the given contact and the contact id itself.

Here is my skeleton code that does not work at all. What do I need to modify? Sorry but I am still new at this.

```
trigger trgr_Related_Staff_Position on Related_Staff_Positions__c (after insert,after update,after delete) 
{

//  Set<Id> setConID = new Set<Id>();
    List<Related_Staff_Positions__c> rsp_List = new List<Related_Staff_Positions__c>();
    rsp_LIst = [Select Contact__c , first_name__c, last_name__c from Related_Staff_Positions__c where Contact__c IN: Trigger.New];
    <ID> id = trigger.get(contact_c);
    if(Trigger.isInsert)
    {
        for(Related_Staff_Positions__c ct : Trigger.New)
        {
            ct.Contact__c;
        }
    }
    else if(Trigger.isUpdate) 
    {
        for(Related_Staff_Positions__c ct : Trigger.New)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Read some docs about [Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm). If you write the trigger on `Related_Staff_Positions__c`, then your `trigger.new` will give you list of `Related_Staff_Positions__c`; not list of Contacts.

Comment: Can you just tell me, I want to do a query with the contact__c id of the record that was just saved, how to get it? I don't want to iterate through every Related_Staff_Positions__c record so I don't want to iterate thought trigger.new but how to do it? Does this make sense?

Comment: As per my understanding you want to iterate on all the child records of the contact.
hope this will give you an idea : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94895/how-to-get-a-list-of-child-objects-from-parent-object-using-apex

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The trigger fired because a user saved a record, it has a contact lookup field named contact__c. I want that id so I can query the Related_Staff_Positions__c object and get the related records to the contact. How to access that id? It can't be in the Trigger.New loop because that iterates thought all records, I only want the current record's contact id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the parent `Contact` id, you have to access the `Contact__c` of incoming child records. And your query filter should be set to filter from child `Id`s and not the `Contact__c`. So your initial query should be like below.

```
rsp_LIst = [Select Contact__c , first_name__c, last_name__c from Related_Staff_Positions__c where Id IN: Trigger.New];
```

And also your trigger should be bulkified as the best practice. Don't consider only one record, but all the incoming records in the trigger context. Iterate through the result list and collect the `Contact` Ids.

```
rsp_LIst = [Select Contact__c , first_name__c, last_name__c from Related_Staff_Positions__c where Id IN: Trigger.New];
List<String> contactIds = new List<String>();
for(Related_Staff_Positions__c rsp : Related_Staff_Positions__c){
    contactIds.add(rsp.Contact__c);
}

// then you can retrieve the other child records which mapped into the given contact
List<Related_Staff_Positions__c> otherChildren = [Select Contact__c , first_name__c, last_name__c from Related_Staff_Positions__c where Id IN: contactIds];
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks. If I can push my luck, I need to add these values into a long text field named "Related_Staff_Positions__c" which is on the contact object, how to do this? I.e. if 3 child records were returned, I need to clear the Related_Staff_Positions__c field, and then add each record on a separate line as line 1 first name, last name role line 2 same thing line 3 same etc..

Comment: This will be a long answer and not related to this post. Try, 1). iterate over `otherChildren` 2). count them and manipulate with you logic. 3). retrieve the contact with `Related_Staff_Positions__c` field and update the contact as you need.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are allowed to compile your code. Because this line:

`rsp_LIst = [Select Contact__c , first_name__c, last_name__c from Related_Staff_Positions__c where Contact__c IN: Trigger.New];`

would give the

```
Invalid Bind Variable error
```

Anyways, you can change the above line to search with the Related_Staff_Positions__c Id like this:

```
rsp_LIst = [Select Contact__c , first_name__c, last_name__c from Related_Staff_Positions__c where ID IN: Trigger.New];
```

You will get Contact ID from this list as:

```
rsp_LIst[0].Contact__c
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Here is what I don't understand, ins't Trigger.New a collection of all records in the given object? If so, how do I get the specific record that I just saved?

Comment: Trigger.New is the collection of all the "NEW" records. Meaning the record you just saved. If you have written trigger on Object A, Trigger.New would contain the record of Object A you just saved either by inserting or updating.

Comment: That was clear. Is it possible for Trigger.New to have more than one record?

Comment: Yes. In case you are updating or inserting the record through data loader or in bulk anyways, then the Trigger.new would have more than one record.